# How to check if the author have a specific role in list of roles?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I was trying to make a check function when if you have a role in a list of role it will work (with a user dev id on the function aswell to bypass it) but it didn't work out.

```py
mod_roles = [792816637488281642,
             792626568488713617,
             827277277488728524]

devs = [341837496763678731,
        382761658858276714]


def is_mod():
  def predicate(ctx):
    if ctx.author.id not in config.devs \
     and any(role.id not in config.mod_roles for role in ctx.author.roles):
      raise
    else:
      return True
  return commands.check(predicate)

@checks.is_mod()
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.send("testing")
```

When I ran it:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command test failed.
```

Comment: "it didn't work out" This doesn't tell us anything.  Tell us what _actually happened_, and explain how that's different from what you _wanted_ to happen.

Comment: `def predicate:` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your lists of IDs and only allow them to execute a command you can built in a different check.

For that we have to check the `id` of the command `author`.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
mod_roles = [] # Insert IDs
devs = [] # Insert IDs
    
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = ctx.author.id # Check the ID of the user
    if user in mod_roles or devs: # If mod or dev
        await ctx.send("Testing")
    else:
        return await ctx.send("You are not allowed to use the command") # No Mod/Dev
```